# Dynamics CRM, Find a CampaignResponse By Campaign And Contact

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Good Day people.

I am a C# programmer for a  long time now.

Recently I started programming in Dynamics CRM, and Everything was going pretty smoothly until today.

Problem was introduced by the PartyList datatype filtering. And I have small experience with LinkedEntities queries, which I think can be the soultion.

In my current position I am trying to find a CampaignResponse which I have its Campaign and Contact.
But so far all I got was the "Cannot add attribute customer of type partylist in a condition" error.

Right now I want a query that takes CampaignId and UserId and find the relevant CampaignResponse.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I searched more and found this post  [Similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352177/error-in-queryexpression-with-partylist)

Just changed it for the CampaignResponse entity.

```
        QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "campaignresponse",

            LinkEntities =
                {
                    new LinkEntity
                    {
                        LinkFromEntityName = "activitypointer",
                        LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
                        LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
                        LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
                        LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
                        {
                            FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                            Conditions =
                            {
                                new ConditionExpression
                                {
                                    AttributeName = "partyid",
                                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                                    Values =
                                    {
                                        userId
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
```